# Array reference issues when using within a function created inside a loop

Tags: javascript

I know, great title right ;-)

Anyway, lets say I have the following code (which I do):

```
function GetArray(i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return [1, 2, 3];
    }
    return [];
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var array = GetArray(i);

    var onClick = function() {
        alert(array.length);
    }

    var html = "<a>click me</a><br/>";
    var element = $(html);
    $("div").append(element);

    element.click(onClick);
}​
```

[See working code here](http://jsfiddle.net/XFBNA/)

Click the 3 links, and notice the alert with the value of 0 for each.

What I want is for the first link to alert 3 when clicked.

Now, before you all start shouting why this is happening, I get that the onClick function is clearing using a reference to the same instance of the array, and thus each iteration of the loop "changes" the array, rather than creating a new one, this is why in effect the last array value is used for all click events.

So the question is, what can I do to get the job done?

I thought of trying to "clone" the array inside the function the that didn't work (I used `.slice(0)`) and probably rightly doesn't work. Plus, I am guessing the it may even just be that the exact same function is being used for all 3 events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever this happens, its a scoping issue.  You need to lock the array  in to the onClick handler each time thru the array.  You do that by creating a closure around it via a self invoking function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var array = GetArray(i), onClick;

    // create a closure around onClick and array
    (function(array){
        onClick = function() {
            alert(array.length);
        }
    })(array);

    var html = "<a>click me</a><br/>";
    var element = $(html);
    $("div").append(element);

    element.click(onClick);
}​
```

Note this will alert 3, 0, 0, as the second and third time thru the leep you return an empty array.

Comment: ...scary... but thanks, makes perfect sense to me, just had no idea how to do it

Comment: this happens with timeouts a lot too